# Getting JSON data using NSURLSessions Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am trying to get JSON data using `NSURLSessions` in the `Objective C`.  I can get the data but I can't save it into an array to use as a data source for another tableview.  I am not really sure what is going on and I'm not familiar with Sessions.  Also when I use a for loop inside the completion block I get an infinite loop of Stop objects. I want to use NSURLSession so I can also cache the data since this data hardly changes but maybe once a month or so.  My code is as follows.

```
-(NSMutableArray *)fetchStopListing {

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kStopList, kApiKey]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];



[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
 completionHandler:^(NSData * data, NSURLResponse * response, NSError * error) {
     if (!data) {
         NSLog(@"Download Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

         //Create a UIAlertController
         UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

         //Create a UIAlerAction that can be added to the alert
         UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

         //Add UIAlertAction ok to UIAlertController
         [alert addAction:ok];
     } else {

         NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

         NSArray *JSONArray = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"stops.stop"];
         //NSLog(@"Hey this is JSON Data %@", JSON);

         self.stopsArray = [NSMutableArray new];

         for (int i = 0; i < [JSONArray count] ;i++) {
             float lat = [[JSONArray[i] objectForKey:@"stoplat"] floatValue];

             float lng = [[JSONArray[i] objectForKey:@"stoplng"] floatValue];
             NSString *stopNumber = [JSONArray[i] objectForKey:@"stopnumber"];
             NSString *stoptitle = [JSONArray[i] objectForKey:@"stoptitle"];
             Stops *newStop = [[Stops alloc] initWithStopLat:lat stopLong:lng stopNumber:stopNumber stopTitle:stoptitle];
             //NSLog(@"This is th newStop: %@", newStop.stopTitle);
             [self.stopsArray addObject:newStop];

             for (Stops *stop in self.stopsArray) {
                 NSLog(@"Stoptitle: %@",stop.stopTitle);

             }

         }


     }
 }] resume];



  NSLog(@"is this getting called");

  //NSLog(@"%@",self.stopsArray[5]);



  return self.stopsArray;
}
```

Comment: What is the specific question to this topic?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Why did you post two comments? Update your question if you need to provide more details.